# How to include the vDSP-Framework (iOS)?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, vdsp

I have problems to include the vDSP-Framework.
I thought it is just that steps todo:

```
#include <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>

void test()
{
  float a[1024], b[1024], c[1024];
  vDSP_vmul( a, 1, b, 1, c, 1, 1024 );
}
```

but if i try to build,I get an error:

```
 "_vmul", referenced from:
```

I think i didnt link the framework. but how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vDSP functions are in the Accelerate framework, if I remember correctly.

From your target's settings on the Build Phases tab, expand the area titled "Link Binary With Libraries".

From there you can press the plus button to add a new framework. Locate Accelerate in the list and add it.

You should then be able to use the functions in your app.

Comment: Do you maybe now, how to bind <Carbon/Carbon.h>. Xcode always print: "/../Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/WebServicesCore.framework/Headers/WSMethodInvocation.h:759: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'CFXMLTreeRef'"

Comment: Carbon isn't for iOS... If my answer solved your problem, please mark it answered using the check mark button to the left.